# Magento 2 Paypal Logger

Tags: magento-2.1, paypal

I have a Magento 2 site that is loading slowly.

There are xhr POST requests to
Request URL:https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/api/logger

origin:https://www.paypal.com
referer:https://www.paypal.com/webapps/hermes/component-meta?xcomponent=1&version=4&env=production

Two of these are successful and then the third gets cancelled.
This whole process delays the loading of the page by 5-7 seconds.

What are these requests and where are they coming from?

Comment: What kind of PayPal integration did you enable? On which pages do you have these requests?

Comment: standard PayPal Express Checkout, happens on all pages

Comment: Do you use custom extensions? What version of Magento do you use?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I solved it by disabling Paypal "In-Context Checkout Experience".

Comment: For me this made the PayPal button disappear.